# Are prior solution attempts required for self-answered questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm facing a dilemma here: Stack Overflow now requires users to demostrate prior solution attempts whenever they post questions that ask for code. In the case of self-answered questions, this rule seems problematic: are users required to demonstrate prior solution attempts when they already know the answer to a question, or does the rule not apply at all in this case?

In order to comply with this new requirement, will I be required to post a redundant solution attempt for a problem that I've already solved, or will it be acceptable to post the question without showing a prior solution attempt (since the only solution that I have so far is a completely working solution)?